# How to complete barplot bars to 100% with a distinct style?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Plotting a bar plot where Y axis reflects percents, how can I "complete" each bar to 100%?

### Example

Consider the following plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

my_df <- tribble(~step, ~prop,
                   "a", 1,
                   "b", 0.8,
                   "c", 0.55,
                   "d", 0.2
)

my_df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = step,
             y = prop)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

How can I create a plot that completes each bar to 100% out of it with dashed lines? Something like:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be use a second `geom_col` to first draw 100% bars, then place your bars on top of it where we have to explicitly set the outline `color`. Note: One downside, which I did not realize at first, is that the outline of the background bars shouldn't but is visible. A fix would be to set the `linewidth` and or the bar width as suggested by @jkd and @r2evans in their comments. A second and cleaner option would be to use a `geom_path` (see below).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

my_df <- tribble(
  ~step, ~prop,
  "a", 1,
  "b", 0.8,
  "c", 0.55,
  "d", 0.2
)

my_df |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = step,
    y = prop
  )) +
  geom_col(aes(y = 1), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", fill = NA) +
  geom_col(color = "grey35")
```

[image]

IMHO, the cleanest option to achieve the same result would be to use a `geom_path` which however requires some effort to create an appropriate dataset to draw the paths:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

make_path <- function(y, width = .9) {
  if (y < 1) {
    data.frame(
      x = width / 2 * c(-1, -1, 1, 1),
      y = c(y, 1, 1, y)
    )
  } else {
    data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))
  }
}

df_path <- my_df |>
  mutate(step = factor(step)) |> 
  reframe(make_path(prop), .by = step) |>
  mutate(x = as.numeric(step) + x)

my_df |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = step,
    y = prop
  )) +
  geom_col(color = "grey35") +
  geom_path(
    data = df_path,
    aes(x = x, y = y, group = step),
    color = "red", linetype = "dashed"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solution is nice and quick. However, it wraps the entire rectangle with the dashed line, so with different colors (other than grey) it's noticeable and becomes confusing.

Comment: In addition to explicitly setting the color you could also slightly increase the grey bar's linewidth.

Comment: Option 1, as jkd suggested: set the line width, `geom_col(color = "grey35", linewidth=2)`. Option 2 (new), reduce the width of the red bars a little. They start at 90% of the data resolution (which is `1` here, so `0.9` is default width), we can do: `geom_col(aes(y = 1), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", fill = NA, width = 0.89)`.

Comment: Thanks @jkd and @r2evans for your comments which both offer valid fixes. Just added a second option using a `geom_path` which extends the bars and avoids the issue with the outline.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way with stacked bars and controlling `alpha` and `manual` scaling of properties:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

my_df <- tribble(~step, ~prop,
                 "a", 1,
                 "b", 0.8,
                 "c", 0.55,
                 "d", 0.2
)
my_df$type <- 'filled'

my_df2 <- my_df
my_df2$prop <- 1 - my_df2$prop
my_df2$type <- 'empty'

my_df <- rbind(my_df, my_df2)

my_df |> ggplot(aes(x = step, y = prop)) + 
         geom_col(aes(alpha=type, col=type, linetype=type)) +
         scale_linetype_manual(values=c('dashed','solid')) +
         scale_color_manual(values=c('red', 'gray')) +
         scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0, 1)) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In base R we can use `rect`.

```
plot(d$prop, xlim=c(.5, 4.5), ylim=0:1, type='n', xaxt='n', ylab='Proportion', xlab='Step')
axis(1, axTicks(1), labels=d$step)
sq <- seq_len(nrow(d))
rect(sq - .3, 0, sq + .3, rep(1, nrow(d)), lty=2, border=2)
rect(sq - .3, 0, sq + .3, d$prop, col=8, border=8, lwd=2)
```

### [image]

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(step = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), prop = c(1, 0.8, 
0.55, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```